# Security of Yahoo's new authentication: On-demand password

Tags: authentication, passwords, email, mobile

Yahoo is trying to remove passwords from authentication and use [on-demand password](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/mar/16/yahoo-passwords-sxsw-encryption-tools-google) authentication system instead.

I wonder how this new system will be secure? Even if somebody steal your mobile can easily access to your email with your SIM, or governments can easily use their power to login in your email by forcing service providers.

Is this **on-demand password** secure at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more secure than a password in some ways, but as you describe, it also makes accounts more vulnerable to other attack vectors.

As a best practice, properly implemented two-factor authentication offers much superior security to a single factor, regardless if that single factor is a memorized password or an "on demand" password.

**Reduced Vulnerability to internet-based attacks**

I can see the logic in why Yahoo has implemented this alternative authentication system however, as one of the primary ways that spammers, automated email-hack bots and human hackers gain access to Yahoo accounts is through password re-use.  Yahoo e-mail is a large service that has been around for a long time; and many of its continuing users are not technically savvy.  Thus, they often reuse passwords on different sites; even going so far as to register with their yahoo e-mail.  Then their account is compromised, and we see spam, scam solicitations (the "I've been abducted please wire money" emails, etc) and the like.

Also, typical malware attacks such as keyloggers and password-interception would be unable to gain access to the account, simply because the password would only be usable once; and once expired a remote system could not gain access.  This reduces vulnerability to a very common method for malicious parties to access others' email.

So, if those users switched to this phone-based password system, these attack vectors would be largely eliminated.

**Increased Vulnerability to Physical Attacks**

As you point out, however, this opens up an entire new attack vector in that if the user's phone is compromised, one could easily gain access to their account.  This changes the attack vector from remote (internet-based hacks from other countries) to a physical hack.  Thus, anyone with physical access to your unlocked device can gain access to your e-mail from another computer.  Users however typically have their e-mail sync with their phone, so if this was the case anyone with access to the device could simply read the e-mail from the phone as well.

**SMS Security**

There is also the question of SMS security.  If a code provided by SMS is all that is needed to login, it is vulnerable to various eavesdropping attacks -- notably from "Stingray" devices provided to law enforcement agencies across the US.   Also as you point out there is the less sophisticated physical attack of stealing the SIM card (and potentially cloning it) and inserting it into another device and triggering the message. This opens up a whole new attack vector, but again it is localized as the attacker must be physically near (or have equipment near) the target.  Two-factor authentication lacks this vulnerability because the other factor (e.g. a password) would not be vulnerable to the same attack.

**Governments have more effective ways**

On the subject of governments, generally they can go through legal means to obtain data from providers so they are less likely to attack a web-based email account via a hack; and either get the information from the provider or force the target to hand over the password or data.

**Use Two-Factor Authentication as a Best Practice**

However, if a user wants to truly take the best measures they reasonably can to keep their e-mail secure, using two-factor authentication is the best option and one should not rely on a single factor, no matter what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer that examine problem from different aspects :)